# PHP: filter specific pattern out of string

Tags: php, regex

My raw output of socket_recvfrom is:

ID IP PING IDENTIFIERNUMBER USERNAME

---

0 127.0.0.1:1234 0 ID123456789 Moritz

1 127.0.0.1:1234 46 ID123456789 August Jones

2 127.0.0.1:1234 46 ID123456789 Miller

---

It is a single string that contains all of this informations in once and just contains whitespaces between the informations. All keys can be longer or shorter.

My problem:

When I `preg_split("/\s+/")` it, then I get a good array with useable data, but when the username contains spaces it creates a second index for this. Not good, all data that comes after this just get destroyed.

I sort the array like this: ID, USERNAME, PING, IDENTIFIERNUMBER, IP

Example by the sorting output with username with one space in it:

---

ID: 0, USERNAME: Moritz, PING: 0, IDENTIFIERNUMBER: ID123456789, IP: 127.0.0.1:1234

ID: 1, USERNAME: August, PING: Jones, IDENTIFIERNUMBER: 46, IP: ID123456789

ID: 127.0.0.1:1234, USERNAME: 2, PING: Miller, IDENTIFIERNUMBER: 46, IP: ID123456789

---

How do I get the information correctly out of the string?

Just forgot to say:

The string begins with: `---------------------------------` in a not countable order. So it can be like 10 characters or 12. 
The string ends with:

```
 (8 users in total)
```

The regex methode looks good. I only need to filter out the other characters.

```
--------------------------------- 0 127.0.0.1:1234 0 ID123456789(OK) Moritz 1 127.0.0.1:1234 46 ID123456789(OK) August Jones 2 127.0.0.1:1234 46 ID123456789(OK) Miller (7 users in total)
```

Last problem:
https://www.regex101.com/r/wP8cW1/1

Comment: preg_match with explode or preg_match_all

Comment: Can you update your example strings to show how the `---------------------------------` and `(8 users in total)` are displayed?

Comment: Edited it at the end

Comment: I've updated the answer and the demo

Comment: Is it all on one line?

Comment: Yeah, that's on line

Comment: The next but maybe the last problem: https://www.regex101.com/r/wP8cW1/1
I need special chars in the username group and also single characters behind space in username, just tested a bit, but I'm not good ( for now ) in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regex

```
(?P<ID>\d+)\s+(?P<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+)\s(?P<PINGR>\d+)\s(?P<IDENTIFIERNUMBER>ID\d+)(\(OK\))?(?P<USERNAME>(\s[A-z]\w+)+)

MATCH 1
ID  [0-1]   `0`
IP  [2-16]  `127.0.0.1:1234`
PINGR   [17-18] `0`
IDENTIFIERNUMBER    [19-30] `ID123456789`
USERNAME    [31-37] `Moritz`

MATCH 2
ID  [39-40] `1`
IP  [41-55] `127.0.0.1:1234`
PINGR   [56-58] `46`
IDENTIFIERNUMBER    [59-70] `ID123456789`
USERNAME    [71-83] `August Jones`

MATCH 3
ID  [85-86] `2`
IP  [87-101]    `127.0.0.1:1234`
PINGR   [102-104]   `46`
IDENTIFIERNUMBER    [105-116]   `ID123456789`
USERNAME    [117-123]   `Miller`
```

**Demo and explanation**

Comment: Looks awesome, I just edited my post. Maybe you can fix that problem too for me.

Comment: You can split by NL and use regex for all lines in foreach loop, for example. On special lines matches will not be occured

Comment: 2 possible issues, If a username has a number it won't match (looks more like these are "user's names" than "usernames" though). This will allow invalid IPs. `\D` can also be used in place of `[^\d]`. I hadn't seen the named capture groups before.

Comment: I agree with `\D`. But i don't know how diff name which is more than one word and has digit :( May be set that 1st letter is not digit

Comment: Ok, I got it finally. Like chris said, the username also has digits. How do I filter this?

Comment: @gDayZ  what about 1st char?

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/rJ6aD4/1 Next, but maybe last problem :D Need special chars and single characters + digits in username

Comment: Or username always 1 word, or 1st character is not digit, or wraping  username in quotes, or newline after username. If nothing,  i can't :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you alredy try explode the string by new lines \n ??

test this code.

```
$str = '0 127.0.0.1:1234 0 ID123456789 Moritz
      1 127.0.0.1:1234 46 ID123456789 August Jones
      2 127.0.0.1:1234 46 ID123456789 Miller';

$lines = array_filter(explode("\n", $str)); 

    foreach ($lines as $value) {
        $t[] = preg_split("/\s+/", trim($value));
    }
```

Now in the var $t you have a usefull data.

Comment: Nope, the username just get split into pieces if it contains a whitespaces